# Creating json file and copy the data to the file through IDE

Tags: python, dataframe

Create a json file called "Students.json" using the command vim Students.json in the terminal, and then copy the following data to the file through IDE:

```
{"name":"Ben","age":"23"}

{"name":"Alen","age":"22"}
```

Comment: What does this have to do with your question title? [ask]

Comment: @Sayse, thanks, I have changed the title

Comment: This is not a question about programming; it is a question about how to use `vim`, which is a text editor. You are not being expected to write a program that creates the file; you are being expected to write the file yourself.

Comment: @KarlKnechtel, thanks

Answer (score -1):

To create a pandas `DataFrame` with the data you provided:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({"name": ["Ben", "Alen"], "age": [22, 23]})
```

Then if you want to do query about it, pandas queries work a little bit different than sql's, I invite you to read the [doc](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/), or maybe a tutorial like non-official tutorial like [this one](https://medium.com/jbennetcodes/how-to-rewrite-your-sql-queries-in-pandas-and-more-149d341fc53e).

*Edit:* If you want to read your Dataframe from a json file use `pandas.read_json`:

Sample file *Students.json*:

```json
[
  { 
    "name": "Ben",
    "age": 22
  },
  { 
    "name": "Alen",
    "age": 23
  }
]
```

Reading json into a Dataframe

```py
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_json('Students.json')
```

If you want to know how to use vim, go through one of the many [tutorials](https://www.google.com/search?q=vim%20tutorial&rlz=1C1CHBF_en-GBGB857GB857&oq=vim%20tutorial&aqs=chrome.0.69i59j0l3j69i60l2.1564j0j9&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8) available online, and get to know how stackoverflow work.

Comment: 1) I need to create a json file called "Students.json" using the command vim Students.json 2) copy the following data to the file through IDE:

{"name":"Ben","age":"23"}

{"name":"Alen","age":"22"}

Comment: Because you have misunderstood the question completely; it is not about programming at all, so better not to attempt an answer.

Comment: The question wasn't properly formulated, the tags are misleading and the title has been changed since then, it's not my fault.